# Patterns for calling Win32 API functions that return ERROR_MORE_DATA or ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER?

Tags: winapi

Functions in the Win32 SDK that return variable-sized data usually allow you to pass a zero-sized buffer, and then they tell you how much space you'll need. They tend to look like one of the following (simplified):

```
LSTATUS RegQueryValueExA (HKEY hKey, LPCSTR lpValueName,
                          LPDWORD lpReserved, LPDWORD lpType,
                          LPBYTE lpData, LPDWORD lpcbData);
```

A naive attempt to call it might look like this:

```
DWORD dwType;
DWORD cbData = 0;
LSTATUS status = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "InstallFolder",
                                 NULL, &dwType,
                                 NULL, &cbData);

BYTE *pData = (BYTE *)malloc(cb);
status = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "InstallFolder",
                                 NULL, &dwType,
                                 pData, &cbData);

// Do something with pData
```

Other functions look like the following:

```
BOOL SetupDiGetClassDescriptionA(CONST GUID *ClassGuid,
                                 PSTR ClassDescription,
                                 DWORD ClassDescriptionSize,
                                 PDWORD RequiredSize);
```

My question: are there any patterns/templates for handling this kind of function reliably? For example if memory actually runs out, or the size changes between the two calls?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer not to send a NULL on the first attempt. Instead, I pass a locally defined buffer, in a size large enough for most cases. Being declared locally, no time is wasted on the allocation, and the only overhead is the chance of running out of stack (which is slim). The required size is returned even if you do pass a real buffer that is insufficient, but only if this is the case you'd have to allocate a buffer from the heap. This way, you're sure to eventually send a buffer that is large enough, and in most cases you'd end up calling the function only once, and without a dynamic allocation.

For example (unchecked):

```
DWORD dwType;
DWORD cbData = SOME_SIZE;
BYTE *pData, pStackBuffer[SOME_SIZE];
bool bFreeData = false;

pData = pStackBuffer;
LSTATUS status = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "InstallFolder", NULL, &dwType,
                                 pData, &cbData);
if (status == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
{
    pData = (BYTE*)malloc(cbData);
    bFreeData = true;
    status = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "InstallFolder", NULL, &dwType,
                             pData, &cbData);
}

// do the stuff...

if (bFreeData)
    free(pData);
```

Comment: That's the right way to do it.  The only bit of trickiness is that the code has to handle deleting in one case but not the other.  Often enough, you wind up copying the result into a string anyhow, so this isn't a serious issue.

Comment: You raise a good point, but I was hoping to see some example code.

Comment: ...because all of the sample code on MSDN leaves out the error handling, and I always feel unsure that I've got it right.

Answer (score 2):

i disagree that guessing with a stack buffer is the best approach. in almost all cases the code simplification of passing NULL beats the negligible performance impact of calling the API twice and allocating a small amount of memory on the heap.

that way you don't need to worry about more complex error handling and alloc/free logic. you also avoid potential security issues.

that said, in the supplied example using MAX_PATH and calling the RegQueryValueEx once is probably the best option.